# Python (newbie): how using imported function into my functions?

Tags: python, urllib

This code will not work

```
import urllib

def loadHtml (url):
    response = urllib.open(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html

firstUrl = 'http://www.google.it';
html = loadHtml (firstUrl);
```

This is the error

```
File "af1.py", line 10, in <module>
    html = loadHtml (firstUrl);
File "af1.py", line 5, in loadHtml
    response = urllib.open(url)
```

I'm at my second day on python .. what's the problem now ?

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

EDIT: **I've not searched for open in urllib because I was not understanding what Python mean by 'module'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `urllib.urlopen()` is what you need, not `urllib.open()`?

You may find more documentation on the library:

- in the official docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html
- Or by calling `help(urllib)`

Comment: Oh my god what a stupid problem ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly as it says, the `urllib` doesn't have a method called `open()`.

Perhaps you meant [`urllib.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen).

One way of resolving things like these without leaving Python is to use the `dir()` function on the module, and throwing on some trivial code to search through the list:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> [x  for x in dir(urllib) if x.find("open") >= 0]
['FancyURLopener', 'URLopener', '_urlopener', 'urlopen']
```

Comment: this is really too much for a second day coder ! But it's a lot usefull !

Answer (score 2):

The error is that the `urllib` module doesn't have a function named `open`.

```
>>> 'open' in dir(urllib)
False
```

See the following snippet on how to know what a module contains.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['ContentTooShortError', 'FancyURLopener', 'MAXFTPCACHE', 'URLopener', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', '_ftperrors', '_have_ssl', '_hexdig', '_hextochr', '_hostprog', '_is_unicode', '_localhost', '_noheaders', '_nportprog', '_passwdprog', '_portprog', '_queryprog', '_safe_map', '_safe_quoters', '_tagprog', '_thishost', '_typeprog', '_urlopener', '_userprog', '_valueprog', 'addbase', 'addclosehook', 'addinfo', 'addinfourl', 'always_safe', 'base64', 'basejoin', 'c', 'ftpcache', 'ftperrors', 'ftpwrapper', 'getproxies', 'getproxies_environment', 'getproxies_registry', 'i', 'localhost', 'noheaders', 'os', 'pathname2url', 'proxy_bypass', 'proxy_bypass_environment', 'proxy_bypass_registry', 'quote', 'quote_plus', 'reporthook', 'socket', 'splitattr', 'splithost', 'splitnport', 'splitpasswd', 'splitport', 'splitquery', 'splittag', 'splittype', 'splituser', 'splitvalue', 'ssl', 'string', 'sys', 'test1', 'thishost', 'time', 'toBytes', 'unquote', 'unquote_plus', 'unwrap', 'url2pathname', 'urlcleanup', 'urlencode', 'urlopen', 'urlretrieve']
```

Did you mean `urllib.urlopen`?

Comment: Wow ! I dind't know the dir method, usefull !!!!!

Comment: In addition to `dir()` there is also `help()` which will not only list the members of the module (or any other object), it will display their built-in help (docstrings).

Answer (score 1):

The reason of error:

```
urllib.open()
```

Maybe you want to do:

```
urllib.urlopen()
```

To see that:

```
>>> dir(urllib).index('open')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    dir(urllib).index('open')
ValueError: 'open' is not in list
```

Answer (score 1):

@realtebo  There are **a lot** of tutorials out there for beginners. You should really start with the basics instead of trying to jump in with libraries. Check it out [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20for%20beginners)